# Finding out the temperature difference

Tags: thermodynamics

If we add 10 spherical bubbles then there will be some change in their area. Is there any way to find out change in temperature of the liquid from the change of its area?

Comment: What temperature difference? The gas inside the bubbles?

Comment: yup and can we get tht how many heat we need to give?